# PostgreSQL PREPARE query with IN () parameters

Tags: postgresql, php, prepared-statement, array

I'm trying to prepare a query from PHP like:

```
pg_prepare($con, "prep", "select * from test where tid in ($1)");
```

and then execute it with:

```
$strpar = "3,4,6,8,10";
pg_execute($con, "prep", array($strpars));
```

The problem is that I cannot pass a series of values built as prepare expects a fixed number of parameters. Is there any way to make the parameters dynamic?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use an array to represent the series of values:

```
pg_prepare($con, "prep", "select * from test where tid=ANY($1::int[])");

$strpar = "{3,4,6,8,10}";
pg_execute($con, "prep", array($strpars));
```

The cast to `int[]` in the query might even be superfluous if the planner is able to infer the type by itself.